# Importing requests module does not work

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the requests module installed on my system.

```
pip install requests
```

Now I am trying to import requests in the rpel

```
import requests
```

It fails with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: Run `pip list`. Does it show in that list?

Comment: I'll give 3:1 odds that (a) you're on a Mac, (b) you installed a third-party Python 2.7, and are using its `pip` to install modules, but are running Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, which of course can't see the modules installed for a completely different copy of 2.7. If (a) is true and you're not sure about (b), what do `which python` and `which pip` say? And, if `which pip` is `/usr/local/bin/pip`, is there also a `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Comment: abarnert spot on. I have exactly the situation that you're talking about. I think I probably used brew to install python and got into this situation.

Comment: Andy it did show in pip list

Comment: Ashwini my python version is 2.7.5

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that you have two versions of Python 2.x, and the `pip` that comes first in your `PATH` doesn't go with the `python` that comes first in your `PATH`.

There are two ways that can happen.

First, you may have, e.g., `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, but your `/usr/local` copy of Python doesn't have `pip`. So, when you run `pip install requests`, that's `/usr/bin/pip`, which installs into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. But when you run `python`, that's `/usr/local/bin/python`, which looks in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Second, even though your two Python 2.x's are in different locations, they may want to install `pip` (and other scripts and executables) to the same place. In particular, `/usr/bin` is usually reserved for stuff that comes with the OS or its package manager, so if you use `/usr/bin/python ez_setup.py` or `/usr/bin/easy_install pip` or many other common ways to install `pip`, it may end up in `/usr/local/bin`. In which case it will overwrite any earlier `/usr/local/bin/pip` that went with your `/usr/local/bin/python`. At any rate, the result is basically the same: `pip` now means `/usr/local/bin/pip`, but it still goes with your `/usr` Python, not your `/usr/local` Python, and installs into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, which `/usr/local/bin/python` can't see.

If your two versions are, e.g., 2.7 and 3.4, there's no problem; per [PEP 394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), either the 3.x versions of everything have to be run with `python3` and `pip3` and so on, or the 2.x versions have to be run with `python2` and `pip2` and so on.

If your two versions are, e.g., 2.6 and 2.7, there is a problem, but you can easily work around it, because you should always have `pip2.6` and `python2.6` vs. `pip2.7` and `python2.7`. You *can* confuse yourself with `python` and `pip`, but you don't have to.

If your two versions are both 2.7, however, there's no way to disambiguate (except by using complete absolute paths all the time, which no one wants to do).

So, why would anyone ever install two copies of Python 2 without knowing what they're doing?

---

The most common reason is that they're on a Mac, which comes with Python 2.7, but they read a blog post that told them to install another Python and didn't explain how to know what they're doing. Apple's pre-installed Python is in /usr/bin but installs scripts and binaries to `/usr/local/bin`. The most popular alternative Python versions are the python.org installer and Homebrew, both of which install to `/usr/local/bin` by default. The fact that Mac users tend to be less Unix-savvy than Linux or FreeBSD users probably doesn't help, but even without that, this is a perfect way to end up with thousands of people who have a `pip` and a `python` that doesn't match, and no idea why.

There used to be good reasons for almost all Mac Python users to installing a second Python. Until OS X 10.6, Apple's pre-installed Python versions tended to be badly out of date, and sometimes broken. If Apple's only giving you 2.4, it makes sense to install 2.6. And doing so is no problem, because `python2.4` and `python2.6` are easy to disambiguate. But Apple has been installing a working 2.7 for years now. There are sometimes good reasons why you need a different one (you need a bug fix in 2.7.7 but Apple gave you 2.7.5, you need a 32-bit build, you need an extra-batteries version like Enthought, you need to build `py2app` bundles out of it, …), but these reasons do not apply to most people anymore.

In fact, many people on StackOverflow seem to have *three* versions of Python 2.7. I'm not sure why this is so common, but they'll use Homebrew to install Python 2.7, and then use an installer from Python.org or Enthought, and now they've got three Python 2.7 versions all fighting over ownership of /usr/local/bin.

So, how can you fix this?

- If you can use Python 3.x, install that and just use `pip3` and `python3` (and `ipython3` and so on), and paths aren't an issue anymore.
- If you don't need a second Python 2.7, get rid of the non-Apple one and just use Apple's.
- Otherwise, do not ever use Apple's Python, do not install things for it, do not touch it; just leave it alone for Apple's own tools. If you use Homebrew, its Python should be higher on the PATH (make sure you've got `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`), and it should let you `pip install foo` without `sudo`, while Apple's won't, which makes it hard to accidentally screw up and install to the wrong one.

---

I've also seen at least one Windows user who had both `C:\Python27` and `D:\Python27`, both on the `PATH`, with the `C:` one first, but `pip` only installed for `D:`. This seems to be far less common than the Mac confusion (probably because Windows doesn't come with Python, and there are no package managers, so the only way you're going to get any Python is by running an installer). And the solution is even simpler here: Windows doesn't need Python, so you can delete whichever one you want.

---

Finally, on non-Mac *nix systems, especially RHEL/CentOS Linux, you may have a Python 2.6 or 2.4 that's needed by the OS plus a Python 2.7 that you installed because you needed it, or a 2.7 that's needed by the OS and a 2.5 installed as a dependency for some "compatibility" package, or similar. Either way, you can easily accidentally install the `pip` for the one you don't actually use (especially if you install it with the `pip` bootstrap instead of your package manager).

The solution here is pretty simple: uninstall that `pip`, and use `yum` or `apt` or whatever to install the `python-pip` that goes with the Python 2.7 you want to use. And get in the habit of using `python2.7` and `pip2.7`—or just add aliases to your profile so that `python` or `py` or whatever you prefer runs `python2.7`.

Comment: This is an attempt to write a canonical answer to this problem, since it's about the 69105th question like this I've seen, but none of them have an answer that's general instead of specifically about the OP's idiosyncratic variation on it. (A sizable fraction of those answers are mine, so blame me for it…) Assuming it happens to answer the OP's specific problem, if we can bang it into shape, I can search for and dup-ify all the other questions.

Comment: I haven't installed any other version of python. My `sudo ls Library/Python` gives only 2.7 and there is no other version in `\usr\local\bin`. My path gives `-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:`,  `which pip` gives `\usr\local\bin\pip` still I'm having the same problem.

Comment: El-Capitan doesn't gives permission to it's user for writing files in library. That was problem.
Solution at - [link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181102/importing-request-module-in-python-doesnt-work-on-os-x/36181150?noredirect=1#comment59997882_36181150]

Comment: I hate python for this.

Answer (score 0):

For devs with similar problem: Intall python3 version directly from the pack file on their website.

DO NOT DELETE OR EDIT ANYTHING ON `usr/local/bin` !

1. `rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`
2. `rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"`
3. Install python3 directly from package on official website.
4. Reopen `VSCode`, (if you don't use it, you must) re-install modules in "Not Found" state, run command: 
   `pip3 install requests`
   and other "not found" modules by command `pip3 install xxxxxx`

Add  `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"`  to your `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

pip install request
-bash: pip: command not found

or

no module name requests

how to fix errors

first:
Download the following and install with python http://get-pip.py

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

[go to the link and download the python script that I provided and then run it or right click and save as]

then after running script "python space (drag and drop the script in terminal)" run "pip install requests" if you get the error below;
-bash: pip: command not found

See the path mentioned in the warning.

then follow this steps acordilly

see the path in yellow?yeah

/Users/macbookair/Library/... etc

type cd in terminal and then drag and drop the bin folder

1.cd /Users/macbookair/Library/Python/2.7/bin {cd /Users/name/path/Python/version/bin )

2. ./pip install requests

after theses steps

Now run your python script again it should work

up vote me if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `Linux` and have both python2 and python3 installed?

If so, you installation by:

```
pip install requests
```

would install the module to python2

So if you run import in python3, it may cause the problem.

Try to call:

```
pip3 install requests
```

to install the module in python3 environment.

Comment: On any linux distro where `pip` installs to Python 2 (most of them at present), `python` also _runs_ Python 2, so he wouldn't be having this problem.