# Importing request module in python doesn't work on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-requests

I have the requests module installed on my system.

```
pip install requests
```

Now I am trying to import requests in the rpel

```
import requests
```

It fails with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I found a answer for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757163/importing-requests-module-does-not-work), but it does't says anything about having python 2.x in same directory.

My terminal outs are :

```
MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ which python

/usr/bin/python

MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ which python2.6

/usr/bin/python2.6

MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ which pip

/usr/local/bin/pip

MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ sudo pip install python-firebase
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-firebase in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=1.1.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-firebase)
Cleaning up...

MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ sudo pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Cleaning up...

MacBook-Pro:~ tanmaybaranwal$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import firebase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from firebase import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase/firebase.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .decorators import http_connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebase/decorators.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Listing PIP modules also doesn't has any `requests` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure that you're using the correct `python` to install something with pip, you can run it via `-m`

```
$ python -m pip install --user requests
```

(if you omit the `--user` flag then you may need root privileges)

Comment: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/tanmaybaranwal/Library/Python/2.7'

Comment: You may have borked something up with your permissions - but you should be able to do `sudo chown -R tanmaybaranwal /Users/tanmaybaranwal/Libarary/Python` to restore permissions to *your* account.

Comment: El-Capitan doesn't gives permission to it's user for writing files in library. That could be problem. Thanks.

Comment: @TanmayBaranwal I could enable permissions succesfully, check Mikko's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870003/pip-install-please-check-the-permissions-and-owner-of-that-directory

Answer (score 0):

With macos sonoma and python3.9+, this is what worked for me:

```
brew install --verbose --require-sha python-requests
```