# Unable to import python requests in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I read this in addition to MANY other things: [Importing requests module does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757163/importing-requests-module-does-not-work)

I am using VSCode and python 3.8.
I am able to import it seems any library except "requests"
Given the ages of the previous posts I hope to know what a good current next step could be, please and thank you

```
import math
import asynchat
import signal
import importlib
import requests  <-----Will NOT import

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json" [api.open-notify.org])

print(response.text)
print(response)
```

Comment: which operating system you are using? Have you tried `pip install requests` or `pip3 install requests` ?

Comment: You can use `pip list` to see whether request installed or not.

Comment: Is there another method without using pip as the pip is NOT an option at this time.

Comment: I reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline. the 'requests' lib is installed it seems vscode just cant link to it. I also checked my system PATH variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think your requests is not well installed. Make sure it's installed with the python you are using with.

Try `pip3 install requests`.